# Getting HRESULT E_FAIL error if copy a big file in Windows Runtime

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I get this error message when I try to copy a big file ( ~500 MB):

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
>   HResult: -2147467259

this is the code I use to copy a file:

```
await file.CopyAsync(storageFolder, name, NameCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
```

Thanks to the developer behind it, it is not very informative.

So how to fix this issue? thank.

*(I'm testing it in Windows Phone 8.1)*

Comment: Answer can be found here: 
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/23866856/374075](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23866856/374075)

You need to buffer it

Comment: Both methods use a buffer, CopyToAsync just lets us set the internal buffer size. TBH I'm not sure why the buffer size throws an exception when its default (which I believe is around 20 KB or so, but not sure) and the method is asynchronous. I would be careful to set the internal buffer too high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested with a 1.5 GB file and was able to replicate the exception. Setting the internal buffer size manually seems to solve the problem, but be aware of how that affects the application. [Read under the Buffer section on MSDN on dealing with large data sets.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh994634.aspx)

The CreateNewFileAsync() method simply creates a new file :)

Best of luck and happy coding.

```
    var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("largeFile.txt");

StorageFolder tempFolder = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;

// Exception
if (file != null)
{
    StorageFile copiedFile = await file.CopyAsync(tempFolder, "copied.txt", NameCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
}


// Setting the internal buffer to 1024 
// Be aware- from MSDN: However, this buffer is allocated on the large object heap 
// and could potentially degrade garbage collection performance. 
// You should only use large buffer sizes if it will noticeably improve the performance of your app.
var newFile = await CreateNewFileAsync();

using (Stream ss = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
using (Stream sd = await newFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    await ss.CopyToAsync(sd, 1024);
    var fileProps = await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
    var size = fileProps.Size;
}
```

Comment: So this way we create a new file and copy the stream. I'm not sure if the file's properties and metadata will remain also or not, I'll check that. Thanks.

Comment: I was simply using the metadata to set a break point and confirm that everything was copied- remove that if you don't need it. You need to copy the file to another file, and with a file that size I wouldn't want to keep it all in memory. The second method in the code above does the same as the first one, with the difference being that the internal buffer size is changed.

Comment: Thanks Iris. As far as I know, StorageFile is only something like emm a pointer to the actual file so we don't have the big file in memory. The reason why CopyAsync() method fails is unclear. Thanks for your help, that works.